# Python configuration module for a web framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration

I'm currently writing a web framework and I wanted to add a configuration module for reading environment variables and a configuration toml file.

Here is the code. The comment in the `Config` class should explain it all.

```
import os
import sys
import toml

BASEPATH = os.path.dirname(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)
print(BASEPATH)
FILEPATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASEPATH, 'config.toml'))
print(FILEPATH)


class ConfigError(KeyError):
    """ Raised when a requested configuration can not be found """


class ConfigBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.basename = ''
        self.default_options = {}
        raise TypeError('Should not use ConfigBase directly')

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        """ called when access like a dictionary
                config['database']['username']
        """
        default = self.default_options.get(item)
        if isinstance(default, dict):
            return ConfigSection(self.basename + '.' + item, default)
        # Check for env var
        envvar_string = '_'.join(self.basename.split('.') + [item]).upper()
        env = os.getenv(envvar_string)
        if env is None:
            if default is None:
                raise ConfigError(
                    'No configuration found for {}. '
                    'Add the environment variable {} or add'
                    ' the key to your config.toml file'.format(
                        '.'.join((self.basename, item)),
                        envvar_string
                    ))
            return default
        return env


class Config(ConfigBase):
    """ load configuration from envvar or config file
        You can get settings from environment variables or a config.toml file
        Environment variables have a higher precedence over the config file

        Use `config['section']['subsection']['key']` to get the value
        SECTION_SUBSECTION_KEY from environment variables or
        section.subsection.key from a toml file
        (usually written:
            [section.subsection]
            key = value
        in a toml file)
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.default_options = self.load_config()
        self.basename = ''

    def load_config(self):
        with open(FILEPATH, 'r') as f:
            config = toml.load(f)
            return config


class ConfigSection(ConfigBase):
    def __init__(self, basename, defaults):
        self.basename = basename.lstrip('.')
        self.default_options = defaults
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3.4 and above?

Comment: Yes. 3.5+ only is fine with me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toml` is a third-party library, so should be separated from the standard library imports:

```
import os
import sys

import toml
```

---

`ConfigBase.__init__` seems a little strange:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.basename = ''
    self.default_options = {}
    raise TypeError('Should not use ConfigBase directly')
```

Why bother to set the attributes if you're then going to throw an error? Also you should use [`NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError) for abstract base classes, by convention.

---

`Config.load_config` seems to be internal; are you expecting it to be called from anywhere other than `Config.__init__`? If not, rename it `_load_config` to indicate that it's an implementation detail. Also note that the temporary assignment to `config` is unnecessary:

```
def load_config(self):
    with open(FILEPATH, 'r') as f:
        return toml.load(f)
```

I'd also note that it seems weird to add a docstring for `__getitem__` that just describes what that method is for, but then not document the non-standard `load_config` at all. Your target audience should already know what `__getattr__` is for (or [where to find out](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)).

---

Talking of `__getattr__`, there's an awful lot of complexity hiding in there. Every other method you've written is nice and short, but this could do with breaking down. To describe it:

- Get the default value
- If the default is a dictionary, wrap it up and return it immediately
- If not, but there's an appropriate value in the environment, return that
- If not, but the default exists, return the default
- If not, throw an error

That's how I'd structure the method:

```
default = self._get_default_value(item)
if isinstance(default, dict):  # or the more general collections.abc.Mapping
    return self._create_config_section(item, default)  # or maybe return ConfigSection(self._create_basename(item), default)
env = self._get_value_from_env(item)
if env is not None:
    return env
if default is not None:
    return default
raise ConfigError(self._create_error_message(item))
```

This reads like the description I wrote above, operates at a consistent level of abstraction (not delving into the details of e.g. how to get a value from the environment or where the default comes from) and reduces the nesting.

You can split out other obvious helper methods, like `self._create_env_var(item)`, along the way. Doing so might highlight to you that it's a little weird to do the same thing two different ways in the same method:

- `self.basename + '.' + item`
- `'.'.join((self.basename, item))`

---

Finally, I don't think the distinction between `ConfigBase`, `Config` and `ConfigSection` is really helping you. You interact with them the two child classes in much the same way; only the initialisation differs. Instead, I might be inclined to do:

```
class Config:

    def __init__(self, basename='', defaults=None):
        self.basename = basename  # should already be lstrip-ped
        if defaults is None:
            defaults = self._load_config()
        self.default_options = defaults

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        ...

    ...
```

Comment: Instead of `NotImplementedError` what about using `abc` module for abstract classes?